# How does BME280 measure air humidity?

Tags: sensor, resistance, humidity

I know that BME280 measures pressure using the piezoresistive effect, I suppose it uses the thermoresistive effect to measure the temperature. How about humidity? Any advice would be appreciated, even starting points for a little Google-fu.

Datasheet: https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/products/environmental-sensors/humidity-sensors-bme280/#documents

Comment: There are several types of humidity sensor in existence; without a datasheet (and possibly even with one) we can't tell which type the BME280 uses.

Comment: Seems the datasheet does not say.  Why does it matter?

Comment: @skvery - Schoolwork... But I already got a decent answer (with a reference, at that). Thank you for your time, anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically low cost RH sensors use capacitance measurement with a hygroscopic polymer layer.

See, for example, O’Dowd, J., Callanan, A., & Banarie, G. (n.d.). Capacitive Sensor Interfacing Using Sigma-Delta Techniques. IEEE Sensors, 2005. doi:10.1109/icsens.2005.1597858

Comment: Precisely what I was searching for! Thanks a ton :)

Comment: You might want to wait 24h before accepting the answer, in case something better comes along.

Comment: Wise advice. Cheers.